# Input box issue with max-length and match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using max length to limit my input to 6 numbers. The issue is it stops after 6. I think the issue is with the regex match I am using to separate the input and the max length.

```
<input type="text" ng-keyup="addHyphen($event)" id="sortcode" name="sortcode" maxlength="6" ng-model="data.branchTransitNumber" required numbers-only/>
```

**Script:**

```
 $scope.addHyphen = function() {
         // $scope.dashed= angular.element($event.target.value);
         var ele = document.getElementById('sortcode');
         ele = ele.value.split('-').join('');
         $scope.data.branchTransitNumber = ele.match(/.{1,2}/g).join('-');

      };
```

**Expected in input: 11-11-11**

**Currently: 11-11-1**

I am also not receving any console errors also.I think the regex wants to put - after two numbers and max length won't allow additional input.

**EDIT**:

After removing the max-length its is working. But how to make it work along with max-length

Answer (score 0):

@Duck_dragon, `maxlength` attribute is used to restrict user to enter specified no. of characters. here you have set `maxlength="6"` thats why it will only allow six characters in input box. Note here it also consider `-` in calculation.

so if you want to allow input like `11-11-11` then you have to set `maxlength="8"`

Comment: Well the fact that it allows me to type `11-11-1` which has length 7 which means `-` is not accounted

Comment: But at the same time `maxlength=8` does the work.  Can you explain why?

Comment: I think addHyphen function executes when keyup, after 11-11, it's only 5 characters, but if you type one more 1, it becomes 11-111, which is still 6 characters, then it add a hyphen before last 1.  It changes to 7.

Comment: Is it possible to use `.macth for first 2 dashes`. I think that will be a better approach

Comment: @lhoro is right, @Duck_dragon if you replace `ng-keyup` with `ng-input`, this will not allow 7 characters.

Comment: `<p class="error" ng-show="data.branchTransitNumber.length < 6">` I have this additonal validation. Should I also change it to 8 then

Comment: @Duck_dragon yes, because branchTransitNumber is  string and will also include  `-`. so if you will use here 6 then it will show an error only for the length upto 5.

Comment: I think you are wrong becuse it accpeted this as input `01-10-00-13` when copy paste. But when typing it works fine

Comment: @Duck_dragon, I am not sure but might in copy paste it will not call `addHyphen` method, so `branchTransitNumber` length will be different, you can confirm by adding log in `addHyphen` method. and pasting string.